# Is it possible to get questions or answers which have last_activity_date > some_value?

Tags: support, api

I am trying to figure out if I can query questions and answers that have the last activity date greater than a certain timestamp.

[This documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#fromdate=2011-11-11&todate=2011-11-19&order=desc&min=10&sort=votes&tagged=skyrim&filter=default&site=gaming&run=true) shows `fromdate` and `todate` query parameters which seem to apply to `creation_date`, but I cannot find an equivalent for last_activity_date.

**Question:** Is it possible to get questions or answers which have last_activity_date > some_value?

Also checked [advanced search](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) and I can see that posts are ordered descending by `last_activity_date`, but cannot find what I need.

P.S. Not sure if it matters, but I am trying this to access posts from a private team (StackOverflow for Teams).

Comment: One workaround is to get page by page until I have values < some_value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [the "Complex Queries" API doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/min-max); you need to set the sorting to `activity` and then the `min` and/or `max` parameters to the unix epoch time(s) of interest.

For example:
[/2.2/questions?order=desc&min=1320969600&max=1321660800&sort=activity&tagged=skyrim&site=gaming](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&min=1320969600&max=1321660800&sort=activity&tagged=skyrim&site=gaming&filter=!6xGkKBjMFEsggJ0SeefEOi.cLR5go-oM2j3)ddWhgEYRREauxt_tI-0tTa15cw(Uuu0EY)

Here is [the live-doc for the above](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&min=2011-11-11&max=2011-11-19&sort=activity&tagged=skyrim&filter=!6xGkKBjMFEsggJ0SeefEOi.cLR5go-oM2j3)ddWhgEYRREauxt_tI-0tTa15cw(Uuu0EY&site=gaming&run=true).

Comment: Yes, it works. If max is omitted, all posts after a certain timestamp are fetched. Thanks.